# Copy folder with wildcard from docker container to host

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers

Creating a backup script to dump mongodb inside a container, I need to copy the folder outside the container, Docker `cp` doesn't seem to work with wildcards :

```
docker cp mongodb:mongo_dump_* .
```

The following is thrown in the terminal :

> Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/SomeHash/mongo_dump_*: no such file 
>   or directory

Is there any workaround to use wildcards with cp command ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems there is no way **yet** to use wildcards with the docker cp command https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7710.

You can create the mongo dump files into a folder inside the container and then copy the folder, as detailed on the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691756/1758853).

If you have a large dataset and/or need to do the operation often, the best way to handle that is to use docker volumes, so you can directly access the files from the container into your host folder without using any other command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 38):

I had a similar problem, and had to solve it in two steps:

```
$ docker exec <id> bash -c "mkdir -p /extract; cp -f /path/to/fileset* /extract"
$ docker cp <id>:/extract/. .
```

Comment: This works well.  2 things: [1] mkdir will fail if used before, unless docker exec is performed with 'rm -rf /extract' (note this completely deletes the files moved inside the container).  [2] may want to use 'cp" inside exec unless you want the files moved inside the container.

Comment: Nice solution. use `mkdir -p` to get round the folder exists issue.

Comment: handy pattern! note that if you just want the contents of `extract/`, and not the whole folder itself, you can add `/.` (forward slash followed by period), i.e.: `docker cp <id>:/extract/. .` ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description))

Comment: I didn't even have to do the first step; seems like `/.` works like I was expecting `/*` to work, it even got dot files.

Answer (score 6):

Today I have faced the same problem. And solved it like:

```
docker exec container /bin/sh -c 'tar -cf - /some/path/*' | tar -xvf -
```

Hope, this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to first get a list of the desired files with `ls` inside the container, which works with wildcards. Then pass each line of `ls` as part of the argument to `docker cp` in a while loop:

In your case:

```
docker exec container bash -c "ls mongo_dump_*" | while read line; do docker cp container:/$line .; done
```

Another simple example to copy all `png` files from `/home` inside the docker container to the current directory.

```
docker exec container bash -c "ls home/*.png" | while read line; do docker cp container:/$line .; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who posted to this issue. In concept, I agree with the for-loop that obtains a list of filenames. However, in my experience (running WSL v2 with Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41), the carriage return character (\r) was included with the string returned from the ls command. Inclusion of this hidden character caused docker cp to complain (" Could not find the file...") even though the file path was valid.* Therefore, striping out \r using tr was the solution.

> for f in $(docker exec -it container_id bash -c "ls /home/results/*" |
> tr -d '\r') ; do  docker cp container_id:${f} /my/local/results;  done

**it is well known that control characters are the bane of software engineers especially when parsing data from parts unknown*

Hope this post saved someone's wall from a forehead indent or hole.