# Copy all files with given extension from docker container

Tags: docker

I'm  have a running docker container with some files in some folder. Some of this files have ".jar" extension. I'm trying to copy it on localhost.

```
docker cp aaaaaaa:/opt/some/path/in/docker/folder/*.jar  /mnt/lib/
```

But I've got error.

`Error response from daemon: lstat` `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/bbbbbbbb/rootfs/opt/some/path/in/docker/folder/*.jar: no such file or directory`
What should i do to copy all files from folder in docker to localhost?

Comment: A similar question was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35806102/1328439). Nothing changed so far

Comment: I hope it is already exist any simple workaround.

Comment: check `docker exec -it your_container ls /opt/some/path/in/docker/folder/*.jar` shows your files

Comment: start the docker with volume to the requested dir

Comment: thank you guys! I have no access to machine with docker right now but i will test as soon as it possible.

Answer (score 8):

```
COPY /root/local_folder/*.file_extension /root/destination_folder/

COPY ["file1.extension", "file2.extension"..., "fileX.extension"] /root/destination_folder/
```

This how we can copy all the files (according to the extension) form host machine to Docker file.